# Converting arrays in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I convert an array like this:

```
array ( [0] => dog [1] => cat [2] => goat [3] => pig [4] => gorilla )
```

Into this:

```
array(array('dog'), array('cat'), array('goat'), array('gorilla'));
```

I'm trying to get started with codeIgniter's table class and it needs to be the format like the one above so that it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $item) {
    $result[] = array($item);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
return array_map(function($elem){
    return array($elem);
},$array);
```

requires php5.3 for anonymous function.
You may make it no anonymous, if you have older version

Answer (score 2):

use `array_chunk()` function

```
<?php
    $a = array ( 'dog',  'cat', 'goat','pig', 'gorilla' );
    print_r(array_chunk($a,1));
?>
```